# How to get content values from any divs to calculate with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to do a function that get the content values from div `<div class="rowtabela">` and read the nodes divs `<div class="item v_...">`.

My code is below:

```
<div class="adicionados" id="tabela">
  <div class="rowtabela">
    <div class="item t_volumes">
      <b>Quantity</b>
    </div>
    <div class="item t_altura">
      <b>Height</b>
    </div>  
    <div class="item t_largura">
      <b>Width</b>
    </div>  
    <div class="item t_profundidade">
      <b>Depth</b>
    </div>  
    <div class="item t_peso">
      <b>Weight</b>
    </div>                              
    <div class="item">     
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="rowtabela">
    <div class="item v_volumes">2</div>
    <div class="item v_altura">1.23</div>
    <div class="item v_largura">4.56</div>
    <div class="item v_profundidade">7.89</div>
    <div class="item v_peso">3.57</div>
    <div class="botao"><input type="button" class="form-control gridresponsivo txt-valor-nf btn btn-danger btn-sm" value="X" onclick="remover(this)"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="rowtabela">
    <div class="item v_volumes">1</div>
    <div class="item v_altura">7.89</div>
    <div class="item v_largura">5.46</div>
    <div class="item v_profundidade">1.32</div>
    <div class="item v_peso">7.53</div>
    <div class="botao"><input type="button" class="form-control gridresponsivo txt-valor-nf btn btn-danger btn-sm" value="X" onclick="remover(this)"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div>                 
    <label>Quantity Total</label>                   
    <input class="txt-volumes" id="volumes" name="volumes" readonly />  
  </div>
  <div>                 
    <label>Cubage (m³)</label>                  
    <input class="campo-cubagem" id="cubagem" name="cubagem" readonly />
    <div>                   
      <label>Total Weight</label>                   
      <input class="form-control gridresponsivo txt-peso-total" id="peso_total" name="peso_total"  readonly />  
    </div>
</div>
```

This "table" with measures is generated dynamically by filling a form.

So I need get this measures and calculate the sum of `quantity`, the sum of `quantity * weight`, and sum of `(Height * Width * Depth) * Quantity`

I tried to get the values with the function below, but doesn't work.

```
$.each($('.rowtabela'), function(index, value) {
    console.log(index + ':' + $(value).text());
});
```

These values are concatenated in a single variable.

Follow the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/c2oz5t9q/

How can achieve it? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a JQuery question.

Incase you have it loaded, an update to your `.each()` iteration with nested `.each()` loops (https://api.jquery.com/each/):

**JS**

```
$('.rowtabela').each(function(index, elTab) {
  $(elTab).children('.item').each(function(index, elItem) {  
    let text = $(elItem).text();
    console.log(index + ': ' + text);
  })
});
```

Use `JQuery`by adding this `<script>` to your **HTML**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: It's missing a single quote in `.rowtable`. I edited but the error is happening: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{'`

Comment: @thiagofred Thanks, i just fixed that missing single quote and the 2nd `.each()` function. You will of course have to add `JQuery` to your project to make that code snippet work.

Comment: Thanks, solved my question. I needed to do some adjustments but this was the main idea.